# Why can data read from a .CSV file with Pandas not be plotted using matplotlib after turning it into integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

**My Goal**

Display a bar chart showing the names durations of the first 30 Netflix shows from a .CSV file

**Relevant Code after Trail & Error**

```
names = pd.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv", nrows=31, usecols=[2])
durations = pd.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv", nrows=31, usecols=[9])
durations[['duration']] = durations[['duration']].astype(int)
```

Then I plot it.

```
plt.bar(names,durations)
plt.title("Show Durations")
plt.xlabel("Name of Shows")
plt.ylabel("Durations (In Minutes)")
plt.show()
```

31 rows are read as the first rows are headers. *durations* is turned into integers as the numbers in the column count as string or something else, and wouldn't work with matplotlib.

**Error Message**

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I don't think Numpy applies with what I'm trying to do, so I'm at a dead end here.

Answer (score 0):

This was able to print out a bar chart for the first 31 values

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv")

names = dataset['title'].head(31)
durations = dataset['duration'].head(31)

plt.bar(names,durations)
plt.title("Show Durations")
plt.xlabel("Name of Shows")
plt.ylabel("Durations (In Minutes)")
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are making two different DataFrames from the csv file and trying to plot them against each other.  While this is possible, a much simpler approach is to create a single Dataframe from the selected columns and rows of the csv file and then plot it as demonstrated below:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv", nrows=31, usecols=[2,9])
df.columns = ['name', 'duration']
df['duration'] = df['duration'].astype(int)
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)

df.plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.title("Show Durations")
plt.xlabel("Name of Shows")
plt.ylabel("Durations (In Minutes)")
plt.show()
```